# Converting function identifier to string

Tags: apl, dyalog

If I have a vector of functions in APL, is there a way to get a vector of the function names as strings? I have tried DISPLAY and ⍕ without successs:

```
      )copy display
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dyalog\Dyalog APL 16.0 Classic\ws\display.DWS sa
ved Thu Jul 25 08:51:54 2019
      functions ← (DISPLAY) DISPLAY
      DISPLAY functions
 ∇DISPLAY   ∇DISPLAY  ∇DISPLAY  
      DISPLAY ⍕functions
 ∇DISPLAY ⍕  ∇DISPLAY  ∇DISPLAY
```

Also, why are there no borders around the elements in the output of the calls to *DISPLAY*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, APL is not a functional language, so there is no such thing as an array of functions.

What you have in `functions` is an 2-train or *atop*: https://apl.wiki/atop

`DISPLAY functions` then becomes an atop of an atop `(f(g h))⍵` and `DISPLAY⍕functions` is a 3-train or *fork*: https://apl.wiki/fork

One way you can get close in Dyalog APL is an array of namespaces that all contain similarly named functions. Then you can call all of the functions with the same arguments in one call:

```
      ns_array←⎕ns¨3⍴⊂⍬
      ns_array[1].dfn←{⍺+⍵}
      ns_array[2].dfn←{2×⍵}
      ns_array[3].dfn←{'wow'}
      3 ns_array.dfn 42
┌──┬──┬───┐
│45│84│wow│
└──┴──┴───┘
```

For more information about possible ways to simulate arrays of functions in Dyalog see https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_Function_arrays.htm

As for the `DISPLAY` function. It requires an APL array argument. These are names of name class 2. You can get the name class of an array with `⎕NC'name'`.

You might find it nicer to turn boxing on with `]box on` for boxed nested-array display in the session.

In fact, use `]box on -trains=tree`, then type "functions" from your example and hit enter. Then the box user command shows a tree structure of the tacit function you have created. Actually don't do that you'll get large ugly output. Try it with `+⌿÷≢` and `avg←+⌿÷≢` instead.

Lastly, I generally have `]box on -trains=tree -fns=on` and `]rows -fold=3` in my session (you can save the settings with Session→Save on Windows and `{2⎕NQ⎕SE'FileWrite'⊣⎕SE⎕WS'File'⍵}'/path/to/session_file.dse` in RIDE.)

Use `]box -?` and `]rows -?` to see the help for these user commands.

Comment: If there is no such thing as an array of functions, what type does the variable *functions* have in my example?

Comment: What you have in the example above is a *2-train* or fork, a type of function composition: https://apl.wiki/forks

Comment: SORRY! ↑ 2-train above is an *atop*, not a fork. A 3-train is a fork.
`DISPLAY functions` then becomes an atop of an atop `(f (g h))` which is applied as f g h ⍵ to an argument ⍵. `DISPLAY ⍕ functions` is a 3-train or fork, similar to (+,-) or (+⌿÷≢).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I forgot about function trains.